# how to create link for my responsive website that "Add to home screen" for mobile user (Android/iPhone)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive and I want to add a link to just create the same effect as the button Add to home screen there is a mobile device.
Instead of explaining to the customer where the button will be a link to "Create Shortcut".

Eventually it will maintain the mobile desk shortcut to the main page of my website.

I added all the icons need only create the link

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks useful https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

Comment: not possible... as youre in the sandbox for good reasons

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually do that just from the webpage. But there is a library just for that is well documented here which is supported on ios and android:

https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

Comment: Thanks for any help,
It seems strange that you can not make such a simple action.

Thanks again to everyone