# Create a link to add a website to an Android or iPhone home screen

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, tablet, homescreen

as you can see today i have a technical question and would like to know if someone already faced to this problem. Actually when we go a website via mobile or tablet we can add this website to an Android / iPhone / Ipad home screen simply by using chrome and follow these steps:

https://www.androidauthority.com/add-website-android-iphone-home-screen-3181682/

Today I would like to know if there is a way to directly create a link where we can click and having the website directly in Android / iPhone / Ipad home screen without opening the drop down the menu by tapping the screen’s three-dot icon at the top right-hand corner and select Add to Home screen.

Comment: Search term you're looking for is "installable progressive web app".

Comment: more like create a link to not opening the drop down the menu by tapping the screen’s three-dot icon at the top right-hand corner and select Add to Home screen.

at the end it will be like a PWA but without creating a PWA because i want simply add my website on home screen of a phone or tablet

Comment: Gotcha, that is different. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: happy you understand what i mean, that's why i told that is a very technical question where the goal is to replace steps by a link :)

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043487/how-to-create-link-for-my-responsive-website-that-add-to-home-screen-for-mobil

Comment: right, but as i can see there is no solution, only a script that i can add to my website ? This question has 6 years old, I though that we found a solution since 2017 !!